# Wrong kohana3 error when i have syntax error

Tags: kohana-3.2

Everytime when i have syntax error, kohana show this:

> HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI

Why? Before i see my syntax error...

My route is fine, whats happening is that every time there is some sort of syntax error , instead of showing the error stack it's telling me that it can't find the route. I think with the older versions of Kohana I was able to see that

Comment: A syntax error in what?

Comment: For example: missing ")" or ";". All syntax error in my code return this Exception. Before i see my correct error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's pretty normal that you don't see a syntax error, because kohana don't know where to start your application.

Go to your bootstrap file in the application folder and fix that specific route.